# Timer in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timer

For example I have a label with text "text" and I want it change automatically in 5 seconds. How do I make action happening in 5 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an `NSTimer`.  Check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).  You probably want either `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:` or `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`.  Here's a quick example:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateString)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

Where `updateString` is something like:

```
-(void)updateString
{
    [textField setStringValue:@"new text"];
}
```

Comment: In addition, send the timer `-invalidate` when you are finished with it if `repeats:` is `YES`.